# Looking for suitable Objective-C object to wrap C void * pointer

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a project that has C code embedded within Objective-C code. The C code produces some void * pointers that I would like to pass between Objective-C methods, so I'd like to wrap them in Objective-C objects to make an `NSSet` or something to that effect.

I have looked into `NSData`, which seems to accept arbitrary data, but wants to know the length of the memory chunk, that I don't have.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not passing a c struct or a pointer of arrays to your objective-c code? You could do a method like this `[myObject setPointers:pointers size:10]; // pointers could be a void ** (array of pointers), size could be the amount of pointers in the array`

Comment: Thank you both, I will think about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is usually used for this task:

```
NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithPointer: myPointer];
```

and

```
void* myPointer = [value pointerValue];
```

Note, though, that the pointer given will not receive any special treatment with respect to memory management. You (and you alone) are responsible for making sure, that the memory it points to remains valid as long as pointers to that memory region exist and are reachable in some part of your program.

Note, though, that using such a value with `NSSet` or as key in a `NSDictionary` might or might not yield the intended effect:

`NSData` is essentially a byte buffer. It actually represents the content of the memory in question. Comparing `NSData` instances for equality compares at byte level. This is one of the reasons, `NSData` needs to know about the length of the memory region in question.

`NSValue` with a pointer value is an entirely different beast. Here, that actual (numeric) pointer value is the essential thing. No consideration is given (when comparing two `NSValue` instances) to the actual content at the address.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Comprehensive answer, thank you!

Comment: @Dirk For [NSNumber numberWithInt:x] we can use @(x) directly, and the int is wrapped. Is any such thing available for pointers as well?

Comment: @neeraj -- It seems, the only supported pointer type is for the `@(...)` autoboxing feature is `char*`. And that one will not be wrapped into an `NSNumber` but converted into an `NSString`, according to http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-c-strings